# Change browser window size programmatically

Tags: browser, responsive-design, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am developing a responsive website. For each and every change I made in javascript, css & html file, I need to test it in all possible screen size in portrait and landscape mode. Normally we used to test it in 3 to 5 different browser window size, and in portrait & landscape. I felt changing screensize and orientation again and again is a tedious job. So planned to write a tool, which will open multiple browser windows in a different screen size with the given url loaded in it. Any idea, or advice how to start this?

PS. If you are voting for deleting this question, please consider commenting with some suggestion how I can start, or is there any free tool available for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE is notoriously easy to program (but you'll only have an IE rendering, no FF nor Safari). Many example can be found googling for "Internet Explorer Automation". For example using powershell: http://harness.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are number of great tools and services for helping test a website in just about every possible OS/browser/size these days.

[BrowserStack.com](http://browserstack.com) allows you to pull up your website on nearly every combination of OS/browser/size and use the site to see how elements and features perform. There are other many other services that do this.

Another option would be a browser extension/plugin like [Chrome's Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh). It allows you to quickly toggle between common (and custom) window sizes. This is the most manual of the three options here, and the only free option.

One final option is [Adobe's Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/). This app allows you to connect several devices to your computer and simultaneously browse a site across each of the devices. It also allows you to remote inspection on each of the connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like Selenium can drive browsers and resize them as needed. Depending on the language of your choice, google for something like: selenium resize browser (language of your choice)